# How to use ForEach on an array of struct in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop, struct, foreach

I have an array of Struct

```
struct StartView: View {
    struct ExampleStruct {
        var name: String
        var keywords: String
        var destinationID: String
        
        init(name: String, keywords: String, destinationID: String) {
            self.name = name
            self.keywords = keywords
            self.destinationID = destinationID
        }
    }

// Created 3 examplmes
        let AStruct = ExampleStruct(name: "Structure A",keywords: "first: school",destinationID: "SAID")
        let BStruct = ExampleStruct(name: "Structure B",keywords: "second: church",destinationID: "SBID")
        let CStruct = ExampleStruct(name: "Structure C",keywords: "third: bank",destinationID: "SCID")
    }

// Created my array of structures
    var StructureArray = (AStruct, BStruct, CStruct)
```

However, I am now trying to create a `NavigationView` with a `List` but I am having issues getting this to work.

```
    var body: some View {
            NavigationView{
                List {
                    for index in StructureArray.indices {
                        VStack {
                           // Text to put ExampleStruct name
                           // Text to put ExampleStruct keywords
                           // Text to put ExampleStruct destinationID
                        }
                        .padding()
                    }
                }
                .navigationTitle("Structure Search")
            }
        }
```

I get a `Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with result builder 'ViewBuilder'` based on the `for index in StructureArray.indices`

I have also tried:

```
for index in 0..<StructureArray.count {
                        let currentStruc = StructureArray[index]
                        HStack {
                            Text (currentStruc.name)
                            Text (currentStruc.keywords)
                            \\ etc
                        }
```

But get the same error. I have searched online for the last few hours and am still lost on how to make this work.  Am I missing something obvious? Would a ForEach be better?

Comment: read the basics of Swift at: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html  
and also do the SwiftUi tutorial at https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/.
Look-up `ForEach(...)` instead of using your `for index in StructureArray.indices {...}`

Comment: Your error is that when you call "var StructureArray = (AStruct, BStruct, CStruct)" it created a tuple. You should call "// Created my array of structures
    var StructureArray = [AStruct, BStruct, CStruct]" instead. Square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below. I have corrected a few of your code. Google the changes to better understand it.

ExampleStruct

```
struct ExampleStruct: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var keywords: String
    var destinationID: String
}
```

ContentView

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    let aStruct = ExampleStruct(name: "Structure A",keywords: "first: school",destinationID: "SAID")
    let bStruct = ExampleStruct(name: "Structure B",keywords: "second: church",destinationID: "SBID")
    let cStruct = ExampleStruct(name: "Structure C",keywords: "third: bank",destinationID: "SCID")
    
    var structArray: [ExampleStruct] {
        return [aStruct, bStruct, cStruct]
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(structArray) { item in
                Text(item.name)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Playgrounds test

[image: Evidence]